# Hazelcast: Execute EntryEvictedListener only once per cluster in client mode

Tags: java, hazelcast

We are connecting to Hazelcast cluster using Java clients from **multiple** nodes.

```
HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(cfg)
```

We need our EntryEvictedListener to be executed only once per cluster.
By default it is executed on all connected clients.

Found how to reach this goal with Hazelcast embedded ([Time Based Eviction in Hazelcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274007/time-based-eviction-in-hazelcast)), but looks like

```
map.addLocalEntryListener(...)
```

is not allowed for client.

So is there any way to execute eviction listener only once per cluster using client?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. You're listener would need to run on a cluster node, since the `local` is directly connected to the underlying partitioning scheme. What do you want to do on the evict event, maybe you can achieve it differently.

Comment: Thank you.
IMap TTL event is very useful to limit some aggregation window time - let's say error message comes, it is stored in map with counter=1, each later similar message just updates counter in that map and on TTL event we decide to generate alert or not basing on counter.

Surely we can use different approaches, but each has downsides:

1. Have some background cluster-wide scheduler - but it will have peeks of CPU usage, more code and more corner cases to handle

2. Store each message and check counter on error arrival - here calculation is performed too often

Comment: 3. We're using client instead of embedded Hazelcast as we want to keep data and processing nodes lifecycle separate

Comment: Sorry but not sure, is there any other question hidden in the messages before?

Comment: Frankly - not sure, just explaining why we are using eviction listener, but if someone have better ideas how to avoid using it - it is really appreciated...

Comment: why cant u register a listener locally in your hazelcast configuration?

Comment: Returned to this problem - no solution so far.
I can't register listener locally as addLocalEntryListener() does not work with ClientConfig.
And even if I switch from the "client" mode to a "lite member" mode, and register this listener on one node only - it will be lost if the node goes down which is not suitable.
What we really require is to handle TTL event only once on any random node from currently running